# How to add a (working) widget button to category WYSIWYG editors?

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, widgets, wysiwyg, category

I need to add the **widget button** to the WYSIWYG editors of some **category attributes**.

There are **two questions on Stack Overflow** with accepted answers:

- [Magento: How to add the widget button to the WYSIWYG Products Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871484/magento-how-to-add-the-widget-button-to-the-wysiwyg-products-editor)
- [Magento: Add Widget tool onto product and category WYSIWYG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335763/magento-add-widget-tool-onto-product-and-category-wysiwyg)

The one problem: this solution **doesn't work 100%** (tested on EE 1.12.0.2 and CE 1.7.0.2).

### What's the problem?

If you set the config entry `add_widgets` to `true` *(btw, you can do that by observing the event `cms_wysiwyg_config_prepare`, that's better than rewriting or overwriting the helper block)*, the widget buttons are displayed. That's fine.

You can even use the "Insert Widget..." button outside the WYSIWYG Editor. That's good.

The **problem** is the widget button in the WYSIWYG editor: you can click on it, the widget manager opens but when you **select a widget type**, the **configuration area doesn't open**.

[image: That's the button not working]

[image: Empty configuration page]

The reason is that there is a **JavaScript error** happening:

"HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy"

[image: Javascript Error]

Even after debugging for some time I didn't find out how this can be fixed. Did somebody of you already solve that problem?

Comment: Do you have a ready to go module for this that reproduces the behavior?  I'm happy to take a look if I've got a reproducible test case.

Comment: Sorry Alan, I totally missed your comment. oserk posted an extension that does it pretty similar. Please note my comment there: the widget button seems to work in Chrome 28. Thanks for your offer to help!

Comment: Struggling with this one, too. Have you found a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I didn't find the reason I can confirm that it now works (at least) in EE 1.13.0.2 and Firefox 33. Resolve the problem by updating Magento and/or your browser to the current version.

Answer (score 1):

@Matthias,

I have created this module for you.

This works for me!

https://github.com/mkdizajn/hairy-tribble

cheers

Comment: It works fine on my end, and I suppose that some other js conflict is in frontend .. I have tested my module on 1.7.0.2 ce version

Comment: Thanks for your effort, oserk. It seems that both your module and my original code now work with Chrome 28 but that it still doesn't work with Firefox 23 (Windows). Is it the same for you?

Comment: Link is now dead, don't suppose you still have this floating about do you @oserk? Thanks.

Comment: Ohh, I was clening my github account and I guess did delete it, will check it out to see if got it home and will update it here..